# Should a std::string class member be a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, pass-by-value, class-members

And why/why not?

Say I have a class which takes a string in the constructor and stores it. Should this class member be a pointer, or just a value?

```
class X {
    X(const std::string& s): s(s) {}
    const std::string s;
};
```

Or...

```
class X {
    X(const std::string* s): s(s) {}
    const std::string* s;
};
```

If I was storing a primitive type, I'd take a copy. If I was storing an object, I'd use a pointer.

I feel like I *want* to copy that string, but I don't know when to decide that. Should I copy vectors? Sets? Maps? Entire JSON files...?

**EDIT:**

Sounds like I need to read up on move semantics. But regardless, I'd like to make my question a little more specific:

If I have a 10 megabyte file as a const string, I really don't want to copy that.

If I'm newing up 100 objects, passing a 5 character const string into each one's constructor, none of them ought to have ownership. Probably just take a copy of the string.

So  (assuming I'm not completely wrong) it's obvious what to do from *outside* the  class, but when you're designing `class GenericTextHaver`, how do you decide the method of text-having?

If all you need is a class that takes a const string in its constructor, and allows you to get a const string with the same value *out* of it, how do  you decide how to represent it internally?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle is a good idea to not use pointers unless you have to

Comment: Remember that you can also _move_ which is more efficient than copying.

Comment: Before answering this question you have to decide whether you want to copy that string or not when the object is copied...

Comment: The intention is that the string never changes, so there's no difference logically whether it's copied or not. I guess it would be wasteful to copy it? But it seems insignificant unless the string is huge (which you don't know in advance if it will be).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should a std::string class member be a pointer?

No

> And why not?

Because std::string, like every other object in the standard library, and every other well-written object in c++ is designed to be treated as a value.

It may or may not use pointers internally - that is not your concern. All you need to know is that it's beautifully written and behaves extremely efficiently (actually more efficient than you can probably imagine right now) when treated like a value... particularly if you use move-construction.

> I feel like I want to copy that string, but I don't know when to decide that. Should I copy vectors? Sets? Maps? Entire JSON files...?

Yes. A well-written class has "value semantics" (this means it's designed to be treated like a value) - therefore copied and moved.

Once upon a time, when I was first writing code, pointers were often the most efficient way to get a computer to do something quickly. These days, with memory caches, pipelines and prefetching, copying is almost always faster. (yes, really!)

In a multi-processor environment, copying is *very much faster in all but the most extreme cases*.

> If I have a 10 megabyte file as a const string, I really don't want to copy that.

If you **need** a copy of it, then copy it. If you really just mean to move it, then `std::move` it.

> If I'm newing up 100 objects, passing a 5 character const string into each one's constructor, none of them ought to have ownership. Probably just take a copy of the string.

A 5-character string is so cheap to copy that you should not even think about it. Just copy it. Believe it or not, `std::string` is written with the full knowledge that most strings are short, and they're often copied. There **won't even be any memory allocation involved**.

> So (assuming I'm not completely wrong) it's obvious what to do from outside the class, but when you're designing class GenericTextHaver, how do you decide the method of text-having?

Express the code in the most elegant way you can that succinctly conveys your intent. Let the compiler make decisions about how the machine code will look - that it's job. Hundreds of thousands of people have given their time to ensure that it does that job better than you ever will.

> If all you need is a class that takes a const string in its constructor, and allows you to get a const string with the same value out of it, how do you decide how to represent it internally?

In almost all cases, store a copy. If 2 instances **actually need to share the same string** then consider something else, like a `std::shared_ptr`. But in that case, they probably would not only need to share a string so the 'shared state' should be encapsulated in some other object (ideally with value semantics!)

> OK, stop talking - show me how the class should look

```
class X {
public:

    // either like this - take a copy and move into place
    X(std::string s) : s(std::move(s)) {}

   // or like this - which gives a *miniscule* performance improvement in a
   // few corner cases
/*
   X(const std::string& s) : s(s) {}  // from a const ref
   X(std::string&& s) : s(std::move(s)) {}  // from an r-value reference
*/

  // ok - you made _s const, so this whole class is now not assignable
  const std::string s;

  // another way is to have a private member and a const accessor
  // you will then be able to assign an X to another X if you wish

/*    
  const std::string& value() const {
    return s;
  }

private:
  std::string s;
*/
};
```

Comment: All of these answers were informative, but thank you for answering all of my questions directly. It's given me a lot to think about/read up on.

Answer (score 7):

If the constructor truly "takes a string and **stores it**", then of course your class needs to contain a `std::string` data member. A pointer would only point at *some other* string that you don't actually own, let alone "store":

```
struct X
{
    explicit X(std::string s) : s_(std::move(s)) {}

    std::string s_;
};
```

Note that since we're taking ownership of the string, we may as well take it by value and then move from the constructor argument.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you will want to be copying by value. If the `std::string` gets destroyed outside of `X`, `X` will not know about it and result in undesired behavior. However, if we want to do this without taking any copies, a natural thing to do might be to use `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` and use the `std::move` operator on it:

```
class X {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> m_str;
    X(std::unique_ptr<std::string> str)
      : m_str(std::move(str)) { }
}
```

By doing this, note that the original std::unique_ptr will be empty. The ownership of the data has been transferred. The nice thing about this is that it protects the data without needing the overhead of a copy.

Alternately, if you still want it accessible from the outside world, you can use an `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` instead, though in this case care must be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally speaking, it is fine to have a class that holds a pointer to an object but you will need to implement a more complex behaviour in order to make your class safe. First, as one of the previous responders noticed it is dangerous to keep a pointer to the outside string as it can be destroyed without the knowledge of the class X. This means that the initializing string must be copied or moved when an instance of X is constructed. Secondly, since the member X.s now points to the string object allocated on the heap (with operator new), the class X needs a destructor to do the proper clean-up:

```
class X {
public:
  X(const string& val) {
    cout << "copied " << val << endl;
    s = new string(val);
  }

  X(string&& val) {
    cout << "moved " << val << endl;
    s = new string(std::move(val));
  }

  ~X() {
    delete s;
  }

private:
  const string *s;
};

int main() {
  string s = "hello world";
  X x1(s); // copy
  X x2("hello world"); // move

  return 0;
}
```

Note, that theoretically you can have a constructor that takes a const string* as well. It will require more checks (nullptr), will support only copy semantics, and it may look as follows:

```
X(const string* val) : s(nullptr) {
    if(val != nullptr) 
      s = new string(*val);
}
```

These are techniques. When you design your class the specifics of the problem  at hand will dictate whether to have a value or a pointer member.